# Kafka Single Message Transform to Replace Substring with another Substring

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using a source connector and would like to replace a sub-string with another sub-string for a specific JSON property.  The replacement will be for all messages of a specific topic.

Is it possible to use "single message transforms" to replace one string with another?

Your input is most appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect is open source framework, so you can add any logic you want

Yes, it is possible, however, you may have to write your own Transform implementation to do so.